# Objects in list seem to share dictionary keys and vaules

Tags: c#, dictionary

Im coding a small program that tries to calculate how many robots can escape to a hole within 5, 10 and 20 seconds, the robots travel by a speed of 10 m/s.

The robots and the holes have two floating point numbers as coordinates and to figure out the distance between the holes and the robots I use the pythagoras theorem.

To keep track of which robot is closest to a hole I equiped each hole with a dictionary with the robots id as key and their distance to the hole as value.

There can also be different scenarios, maxium 10, with different numbers and holes.

Input looks like this, where the first number N is the number of robots in the field followed by N lines of X/Y coordinates. Second is the number M which is the number of holes followed by M lines of X/Y coordinates.

The input ends with a 0.

```
3
0.0 0.0
10.0 0.0
0.0 10.0
3
99.0 0.0
0.0 1000.0
1000.0 1000.0
3
0.0 0.0
100.0 0.0
200.0 0.0
2
95.0 50.0
105.0 50.0
0
```

Theese are my classes

```
    class Robot
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public double PosX { get; private set; }
    public double PosY { get; private set; }
    public bool isHiding { get; set; }

    public Robot(double posX, double posY, int id)
    {
        PosX = posX;
        PosY = PosY;
        Id = id;
    }
}

class Hole
{
    public Dictionary<int, double> Candidates { get; set; }        
    public double PosX { get; private set; }
    public double PosY { get; private set; }
    public bool isOccupied { get; set; }
    public Hole(double posX, double posY)
    {
        PosX = posX;
        PosY = posY;
    }
}

class Scenario
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public List<Duration> Durations { get; set; }

    public Scenario(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

class Duration
{
    public int Time { get; private set; }
    public int Survivors { get; set; }
    public List<Robot> Robots { get; set; }
    public List<Hole> Holes { get; set; }

    public Duration(int time)
    {
        Time = time;
    }

}
```

I collect the input like this, and this is where i belive something might be the problem. Although to me it seems that all objects are instanciated properly.

```
void CollectInputs()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Scenario scenario = new Scenario(i + 1);
        List<Duration>  durations = new List<Duration>();

        List<Robot> robots = new List<Robot>();
        List<Hole> holes = new List<Hole>();

        int newRobots = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (newRobots == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        for (int iii = 0; iii < newRobots; iii++)
        {
            string[] inputCoordsRobot = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            Robot robot = new Robot(double.Parse(inputCoordsRobot[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(inputCoordsRobot[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), iii + 1);
            robots.Add(robot);
        }

        int newHoles = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int iii = 0; iii < newHoles; iii++)
        {
            string[] inputCoordsHole = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            Hole hole = new Hole(double.Parse(inputCoordsHole[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(inputCoordsHole[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            holes.Add(hole);             
        }

        for (int ii = 5; ii <= 20; ii = ii + ii)
        {

            Duration duration = new Duration(ii);

            duration.Robots = new List<Robot>(robots);
            duration.Holes = new List<Hole>(holes);

            durations.Add(duration);

            scenario.Durations = new List<Duration>(durations);

        }
        _scenarios.Add(scenario);
    }

}
```

This is the distance calculation.

```
void UnleashStorm()
        {
            foreach (var scenario in _scenarios)
            {
                foreach (var duration in scenario.Durations)
                {
                    double movementCapacity = duration.Time * 10.0f;

                    foreach (var hole in duration.Holes)
                    {
                        Dictionary<int,double> robotsInRange = new Dictionary<int, double>();

                        foreach (var robot in duration.Robots)
                        {
                            double distanceToX = robot.PosX > hole.PosX ? robot.PosX - hole.PosX : hole.PosX - robot.PosX;
                            double distanceToY = robot.PosY > hole.PosY ? robot.PosY - hole.PosY : hole.PosY - robot.PosY;

                            double distanceToHole = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(distanceToX, 2) + Math.Pow(distanceToY, 2));

                            if (distanceToHole <= movementCapacity)
                            {
                                robotsInRange.Add(robot.Id, distanceToHole);
                            }

                        }

                        hole.Candidates = new Dictionary<int, double>(robotsInRange);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I noticed in the debugger that for each duration if something is added to a specific holes dictoinary the key and value seem to be shared between that same hole in all duration calculations.

Im thinking this is a problem with me throwing pointers around in a bad way either in the input collection method or in the calculating distance method but I cant seem to figure this one out.

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only dictionary in here is `Dictionary<int,double>`. Most dictionary questions are where folks have a complex type as the key, and make a mess of it - however, `int` and `double` know how to behave, so : forget about the dictionary itself, that isn't the problem. If the data is a mess, you'll have to debug why, but : I don't see enough context there for us to unpick that

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. The data used when this problem occurs is that of the input shown above. Is there anything I might add to give a better picture of this problem?

Comment: `duration.Holes = new List<Hole>(holes);` you create a new list and assgin the reference of  `holes` to the new list. This causes the problem when you modified hole `hole.Candidates = new Dictionary<int, double>(robotsInRange);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not from Dictionary, it's from the reference copy in `duration.Holes = new List<Hole>(holes);` where all `durations.Holes` share the reference of `holes` list you created in `CollectInputs`

To avoid this, you need to assign values of `holes` to `duration.Holes`. One option is to make `Hole` class cloneable

```
        class Hole : ICloneable
        {
            public Dictionary<int, double> Candidates { get; set; }
            public double PosX { get; private set; }
            public double PosY { get; private set; }
            public bool isOccupied { get; set; }
            public Hole(double posX, double posY)
            {
                PosX = posX;
                PosY = posY;

            }

            public object Clone()
            {
                var hole = new Hole(this.PosX, this.PosY)
                {
                    isOccupied = this.isOccupied,
                    Candidates = this.Candidates
                };
                return hole;
            }
        }

    // and replace 
    // duration.Holes = new List<Hole>(holes);
    // to 
    duration.Holes = new List<Hole>(holes.Select(x=>x.Clone() as Hole));
```

You may have other places where you use reference, check it.

Comment: Aha thank you friend for your excellent solution and understanding of my code, this solved my problem.